# Azure geo-replication: Can't create a secondary server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, database-replication, geo-replication

I have an Azure SQL data base on a premium tier
I try to activate Geo-replication on the preview portal.

I clicked Server name on CREATE SECONDARY blade
I then selected CREATE A NEW SERVER on SERVER blade
I filled the form, but the OK button still stay disabled

Bellow is a screen copy:

What should I do more?

[image]

Comment: In which location your primary server is? Is it upgraded to V12 too? That is the only thing that can go wrong based on the UI ..

Comment: I tried unsuccessfully different locations

Comment: i tried unsuccesfully different locations. But I discovered it's working fine when setting "create V12 server" at NO. I don't understand why this option is avalable if not working

Comment: Hi Frederic , can you try to do this again? and let me know if this issue is still occurring? 
I sent you and email regarding this question @ amethyste16 [at] Hotmail [dot] com

Comment: The expectation is both primary secondary servers are of same type (SQL V12) or pre V12 I believe.

Comment: @Boboyum I tried again. OK button is OK now (what did you change?). But the wizzard breaks later now. I can see the animation, but 10 seconds later it stops and does not create the geo-replication relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some exchange with a guy from Microsoft.
This is the situation:

- OK button works now (I don't know what they did)
- But later the Geo replication fails

This is due to the fact that Azure thinks my server name is already in use. This is true I used it once, but I also delete it and it is not displayed on the SQL server blade.

So there is still an issue in the portal to be clarified and fixed. But everything works fine if I am using another server name.

Comment: Azure SQL DB Servers need to be unique. That said, we acknowledge that there is work to be done on the pre-validation of server names to ensure uniqueness before the portal allows the user to proceed.